# Bubble Sort in ANSI C

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have an assignment that needs the data sorted. Ive been trying to use the bubble sort method to sort the data however it does not seem to work. I have attached the assignment to allow you to understand what I am doing. I am not looking for the answer but for help. I am also wondering how the `sales_id` would incorporate into that since it is not an array and also needs to be sorted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct sales_commissions {
    float commissions[3];
};

struct sales {
    char sales_name[30];
    int sales_id;
    struct sales_commissions sc;
};

void comp_name(char company_name[15]);
int agent_number();
void agent_info(char[], int sales_agents, int sales_id, float[]);
void sorting(char[], int sales_agents, int sales_id, float[], char []);

main() {
    /* --- Declaring Variables --- */
    char company_name[15];
    char c;
    int i;
    int sales_agents;

    struct sales Sales;

    comp_name(company_name);    

    sales_agents = agent_number();
    
    agent_info(Sales.sales_name, sales_agents, Sales.sales_id, Sales.sc.commissions);
    
    sorting(Sales.sales_name, sales_agents, Sales.sales_id, Sales.sc.commissions, company_name);

    return 0;
}

void comp_name(char company_name[15]) {
    printf("Welcome to the Sears Commission analysis\n");

    printf("Enter the Company Name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", company_name);
    
    return company_name;
}

int agent_number() {
    char c;
    int sales_agents = 0;

    printf("Enter the number of sales agents (1 - 20): ");
    scanf("%d", &sales_agents);
    while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);

    while (sales_agents < 1 || sales_agents > 20) {
        while (sales_agents == 0) {
            printf("*** No number of sales agents entered. Quitting program. ***\n");
            return 0;
        }

        printf("*** Invalid number of sales agents. Please enter 1 - 20. ***\n");
        printf("Enter the number of sales agents (1 - 20): ");
        scanf("%d", sales_agents);
        while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
    }
    return sales_agents;
}

void agent_info(char sales_name[], int agent_number, int sales_id,
                float commissions[])
{
    char c;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < agent_number; i++) {
        printf("Enter the name of sales agent #%d:  ", i + 1);
        scanf("[^\n]s", sales_name[i]);
        while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
        
        printf("Enter ID number for sales agent #%d:  ", i + 1);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", sales_id);                
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
        
        printf("Enter Commission 1 for sales agent #%d:  ", i + 1);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &commissions[0]);                
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);

        printf("Enter Commission 2 for sales agent #%d:  ", i + 1);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &commissions[1]);                
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);

        printf("Enter Commission 3 for sales agent #%d:  ", i + 1);
        scanf("%[^\n]s", &commissions[2]);                
        while ( (c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
    }
    return sales_name;
}

void sorting(char sales_name[], int agent_number, int sales_id,
             float commissions[], char company_name[])
{
    int i;
    int u;
    int temp;
    char c;
    char temp2;
    char swapped = 'Y';
    
    printf("Did we get to sorting?\n");
    
    while (swapped == 'Y') {
        swapped = 'N';

        for (i = 0; i < agent_number - 1; i++) {
            if (commissions[i] < commissions[i + 1]) {
                temp = commissions[i];
                commissions[i] = commissions[i + 1];
                commissions[i + 1] = temp;

                for (u = 0; u < 50; u++) {
                    temp2 = sales_name[i][u];
                    sales_name[i][u] = sales_name[i + 1][u];
                    sales_name[i + 1][u] = temp2;
                }
                swapped = 'Y';
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", swapped);
    
    printf("\n\nCommission Report -- %s\n\n", c);

    printf("Agent Name\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < agent_number; i++) {
        printf("%-12s     \n\n", sales_name[i]);
    }
}
```

I was trying to first try and see if I could get a bubble sort running given what is an array. I have tried to see if it could pair the name to the commission.

**P.S I am exhausted so I will be checking responses in the morning, pardon my delayed response.**

Comment: You misdeclared `temp` as an `int`.  It obviously needs to be `float`, since that's the type of the elements of `commissions`.  As it is now, when you assign a `float` to `temp`, any fractional part is lost (and you also risk overflow).

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you so much for catching that! I appreciate it and corrected that. I have a print statement to see if it gets to the function and it does, however it seems that anything after that it does nothing. Thank you again so much for your time!

Comment: Change all occurrences of `char c;` to `int c;` when using with `getchar()` and testing for EOF... EOF does not fit into a `char`... Also, change all occurrences of `"%[^\n]s"` by dropping the 's'... This is a common beginner's mistake.

Comment: Your example is incomplete: missing headers, definition of `struct sales`, and `main`. Please include a complete [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question, so we don't have to speculate around what is missing.

Comment: You have a lot of little errors in your code that compiler warnings should catch, mostly inonsistencies between `char[N]`, `char *` and plain `char`. For example, your `swapped` variable is a `char`, so you cannot print it with ´%s`.

Comment: You can create structure `Agent` and add all information related to an agent there. And then you can call bubble sort on the array of structs.

Comment: [`qsort`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) in `<stdlib.h>` is pretty good if you don't need stability, (and the point of the exercise it something else.)

Comment: Can you post a full program, including the `#include` lines, the definitions of structures and global variables.

Comment: Are you required to implement your own sorting method? Otherwise, using the standard [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) is the easiest option. Bubblesort is rarely used in practice due to its bad performance unless the data is known to be "almost" sorted in advance.

Comment: @chqrlie I apologize for not noticing that those were not included in the main post. I thought they were. This comment will include those. 

`#include <stdio.h>



struct sales_commissions
{
    float commissions[3];
};

struct sales
{
    char sales_name[30];
    int sales_id;
    struct sales_commissions sc;
};
void comp_name(char company_name[15]);
int agent_number();
void agent_info(char[], int sales_agents, int sales_id, float[]);
void sorting(char[], int sales_agents, int sales_id, float[], char []);
`

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in the code.  You should enable more compiler warnings and fix the problems reported. Use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Wall -Weverything -Werror`.

The sort function prototype is incorrect: the argument `Sales.sales_name` is probably a 2D array `char sales_name[20][50]` and the `sales_id` is probably also an array, so the function prototype should be

```
void sorting(char sales_name[][50], int agent_number, int sales_id,
             float commissions[], char company_name[]);
```

Furthermore, the swapping operation `sales_name[i] = sales_name[i + 1][u];` should store to `sales_name[i][u]` instead and the `temp` variable must have the same type as the `commissions` element type: `float`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void sorting(char sales_name[][50], int agent_number, int sales_id[],
             float commissions[], char company_name[]) {
    char swapped = 'Y';
    
    while (swapped == 'Y') {
        swapped = 'N';

        for (int i = 0; i < agent_number - 1; i++) {
            if (commissions[i] < commissions[i + 1]) {
                // swap the commission value?
                float temp = commissions[i];
                commissions[i] = commissions[i + 1];
                commissions[i + 1] = temp;

                // swap the agent ID?
                int id = sales_id[i];
                sales_id[i] = sales_id[i + 1];
                sales_id[i + 1] = id;

                // swap the agent name
                for (int u = 0; u < 50; u++) {
                    char temp2 = sales_name[i][u];
                    sales_name[i][u] = sales_name[i + 1][u];
                    sales_name[i + 1][u] = temp2;
                }
                swapped = 'Y';
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nCommission Report -- %s\n\n", company_name);

    printf("Agent Name  Commission\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < agent_number; i++) {
        printf("%-12s  %.2f\n", sales_name[i], commissions[i]);
    }
}
```

The `while` loop to read and discard the remainder of the input line is incorrect too: `c` must have type `int` to handle all possible byte values (all values of the type `unsigned char`) and the negative value `EOF`.  You should encapsulate this inside a function:

```
// read and discard the remainder of the input line
// return the newline if found or EOF if none before the end of file
int flush_stdin(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF)
        continue;
    return c;
}
```

Most of the `scanf` conversions are incorrect:

- `scanf("[^\n]s", sales_name[i])` should be `scanf("%49[^\n]", sales_name[i])`
- `scanf("%[^\n]s", sales_id)` should be `scanf("%d", &sales_id[i])`
- `scanf("%[^\n]s", &commissions[0])` should be `scanf("%f", &commissions[0])` but it unclear what the `commissions` array represents: is the one per agent?

Instead of using a separate array for each sales agent data item, you should define a structure to describe each sales agent and use an array of such structures.

Comment: Each agent will have three values for the array (since they will all have 3 commissions) but it will print out as a single value of the three added together for that agent. Then the total of all added commissions of all the agents entered will be displayed under them all. Theres also the average of the commissions of each agents commission, then under that theres the average of all the averages. If this is not clear enough I will try and think of another way to explain it. This is just currently how it came to mind at the moment.